# How to bind form to model in NancyFX

Tags: nancy

I'm new to NancyFX and trying to simply bind a posted form to my model.

In the module when trying to access the posted values I run following statement:

```
        string email = this.Context.Request.Form["Email"];
        Debug.WriteLine(email);
```

Result is:
 "Nancy.DynamicDictionaryValue" instead of posted value

Can anybody tell me what newbie mistake I'm doing:

The form looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="account">
    <input type="text" id="Email" />
    <input type="password" id="Password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

the routing in Module contructor:

```
       Post["/"] = parameters => CreateAccount(parameters);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dynamic dictionary returns a dynamic value, if you cast it to a string (implicitly or explicitly) you'll get what you want, or just use the build in model binder https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Model-binding

Comment: But that is just the problem. I do not get the values I posted. I've tried this as well ->           CreateAccountModel model = this.Bind();
where model.Email is null after the binding

Comment: @JanOhlson you should also be using the name attribute in your html, not id?

Answer (score 3):

Just adding to the correct answer above in the hope it is useful to nancy-newbies like me.

Because the Nancy Form and Query are of type `dynamic` you can access the values using the name of the form or query-string param (see `terms` and `max` in the example code). I use a simple base class just to make the syntax terser throughout the rest of my modules.

**Note**: The ExpandoObject `Model` in the base class is there so I can just throw values at my view-model and not have to worry about cluttering things up with strongly typed data-transfer classes (this also helps prevent exposing any secret domain instance data).

```
public class SearchModule : _BaseModule
{
    public SearchModule(ISearchService searchService)
    {
         Get["/search"] = _ =>
            {
                if (!Query.terms.HasValue) return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                var terms = (string) Query.terms;
                var max = (Query.max.HasValue) ? (int) Query.max : 3;
                Model.SearchResults = searchService.GetResults(max, terms);
                ...
            };
    }
}

public class _BaseModule : NancyModule
{
    protected dynamic Model = new ExpandoObject();
    public dynamic Query { get { return Request.Query; } }
    public dynamic Form { get { return Request.Form; } }
}
```